# excel index match with pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, match

I am trying replicate the excel index match in pandas so as to produce a new column which copy's the date on the first occurrence of value in colB being exceeded or matched by value in colC

```
        date               colA  colB  colC  colD   desired_output
0  2020-04-01 00:00:00            2      1      e      2020-04-02 00:00:00 
1  2020-04-02 00:00:00     8      4      4      d      2020-04-02 00:00:00
2  2020-04-03 00:00:00            1      2      a      2020-04-03 00:00:00
3  2020-04-04 00:00:00     4      2      3      b      2020-04-04 00:00:00
4  2020-04-05 00:00:00     5      3      1      c      2020-04-07 00:00:00
5  2020-04-06 00:00:00     9      4      1      m
6  2020-04-07 00:00:00     5      3      3      c      2020-04-07 00:00:00
```

Here is the code that i have tried so far, unsuccessfully:

col_6 = []

for ind in df3.index:

```
if df3['colC'][ind] >= df3['colB']:
    col_6.append(df3['date'][ind]
else:
    col_6.append('')
```

df3['desired_output'] = col_6

and have also tried:

col_6 = []

for ind in df3.index:

```
if df3['colB'][ind] <= df3['colC']:
    col_6.append(df3['date'][ind]
else:
    col_6.append('')
```

df3['desired_output'] = col_6

...this second attempt has come the closest, but only produces results when the 'if' conditions occur within the same index row in the dataframe. For instance, the value of 'colB' in index row 4 is exceeded by value of 'colC' in index row 6 but my attempted code is unsuccessful at capturing this sort of occurrence

Comment: please post the expected output for clarity and your try code

Comment: I have just added the expected output and the try code, massive oversight on my part not sending initially.

Comment: Usually Excel's `INDEX/MATCH` is to search across different ranges or worksheets. Your needs would be a simple Excel `IF` formula.

Comment: Yes I agree. In excel this would be quite simple. However, what I trying to do is part of a larger python script and which is why i need to perform this operation with pandas